# Flask Testing: request.files is empty

Tags: python, flask

I'm hitting a route in my tests which accepts file upload fields. This is the test code:

```
    video_file = open(test_helpers.get_dummy_file('test_video.mp4'), 'rb')
    image_file = open(test_helpers.get_dummy_file('test_photo.jpg'), 'rb')
    response = self.app.post(
        '/new-ad/write-details',
        buffered=True,
        content_type='multipart/form-data',
        data={
            'location_id': db.session.query(Location).first().id,
            'category_id': db.session.query(Category).first().id,
            'title': 'test title',
            'body': 'test body',
            'add_video': (video_file.read(), 'test_video.mp4'),
            'add_images': (image_file.read(), 'test_photo.jpg')})
```

In my route, I'll put in a simple `print(request.files` and I notice that it's an empty `ImmutableDict`.

Using the browser, I can upload files just fine.

I also put in `print(image_file)` to make sure these test files are what they should be.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out right after I posted it...

I basically omitted the `.read()` parts and everything seems to work.